# Refresh command output in alias

Tags: shell-script, alias, bashrc

When I set in `.bashrc` something like:

```
alias="docker stop $(docker ps -aq)"
```

or

```
alias="echo $(ls -l ~)"
```

obviously never refreshes the command output in $(), so is an string...

So, my question is, there is any way to refresh the command output used as variable ?

Comment: use single quotes

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, thank you, that’s was I looking for. Put it as answer, if you want, and I’ll mark it as correct.